# Display username in template with custom user model as welcome message

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-bootstrap4

I want to display  username in base.html but it's not working.I am learning django if you see any mistake please tell.

```
# settings.py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 
'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
'social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',

)
```

User model

```
class accountUser(AbstractBaseUser):
  email             = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
  username          = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
  date_joined       = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
  last_login        = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
  is_admin          = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_active         = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  is_staff          = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_superuser      = models.BooleanField(default=False)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username',]
```

base.html

```
<li><a href="#">{{ accountUser.username }}</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
```

Comment: you can access object fields if you are passing the object in context while rendering the template from view. You probably are not rendering `base.html` anywhere or if you are then you are using incorrect context variable.

Comment: I don't get it what do you mean by incorrect context variable

Comment: you are not passing an actual `accountUser` object to the template

Comment: Then how can pass an actual accountUser object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

request always is added in context for rendering template, so you can code like below:

```
<li><a href="#">{{ request.user.username }}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to pass it to `base.html`

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

def myview(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html`, context={"user": request.user})

#base.html
<li><a href="#">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
```